# Is there any better way for creating by code a directive object?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

`angular.element('<my-directive></my-directive>')`

Why I can not just say the name of my directive ?
Seems so strange to write HTML line inside js...

Any better way for creating instance of directive in memory?

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern for writing directives is like this.

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', ['myApp.services'])
    /*
        toggleclass
        A generic directive for toggling a class directly on an element
        or by specifying a toggle-target option
        eg. toggleclass="{class: 'open', target='.element'}"

    */
    .directive('toggleclass', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                element.on('click', function(){
                    var ops = scope.$eval(attrs.toggleclass);

                    // If a toggle-target is set
                    if(ops.target){
                        element = angular.element(document.querySelector(ops.target));
                    }

                    // Toggle the class
                    element.toggleClass(ops.class);

                });
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: This is the recepy for creating directive, but what if you want to create instance of it not by writing directive in index.html

Comment: Then i'm not sure why you would use a directive. Sounds like you just need a function to run in your controller? The more info you provide in your original post the more I can help :).

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.element('<my-directive></my-directive>')
```

AFAIK this piece of code doesnt really create a directive,it just create an element tagged "my-directive".

You dont need the closing tag by the way. `angular.element('<my-directive>')` is valid.

If you want to get verbose : `angular.element(document.createElement('my-directive'))` .

It is some kind of **jQuery** light.

to instanciate a directive you need to compile some DOM and pass a scope.

```
var e = angular.element('<my-directive></my-directive>');

$compile(e)($scope);
```